# Compiler generating wrong call to template function?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct static_type_array
```

Inside of it I have these functions:

```
inline T* Get(s32 Index)
inline const T* Get(s32 Index) const 
inline T* operator[](s32 Index)
inline const T* operator[](s32 Index) const
```

I create these variables:

```
static_type_array<vertex> Vertices;
static_type_array<u32> Indices;
```

The thing is, when I call to `Indices[Index]` I get to the function:

```
static_type_array<u32>::operator[]...
```

as expected.. but inside this function (`operator[]`) I call to `Get` with the index I get from the call, and this goes to:

```
static_type_array<vertex>::Get(s32 Index)...
```

which is really odd..
I tried to figure out what was happening, and I saw something strage..

This code:

```
inline T* operator[](s32 Index)
{
    T* Result = Get(Index);
    return Result;
}
```

will generate a call to the appropriate function (`<u32>`), while this code:

```
inline T* operator[](s32 Index)
{
    return Get(Index);
}
```

will generate a call to the wrong function (`<vertex>`)...

I thought maybe its the inline but I tried removing it and its not that.

Any idea what is going on with my code?

EDIT: If I am missing any information let me know.

Comment: [mcve] required! Imposing on ***everyone else*** to try and reproduce what's going on with your disjoint snippets of code is highly inefficient.

Comment: @CraigYoung I'll update the snippet in a minute

Comment: I cant seem to be able to reproduce the problem.. I'll try to figure out what is going on because I see that even the ctor begin called is the wrong one to begin with..

Comment: And that's a prime example why MCVE should be the first step. ;)  Good luck.

Comment: @CraigYoung Thanks, I'll try it first before I post a question next time :)

Comment: I don't really understand why, but this flag: `-opt:ref` seems to be causing the problem.. when I removed it everything is fine now.. which according to MSDN `eliminates functions and data that are never referenced` which is odd because I did use them..